# Numbering facts in PCTeX

Tags: numbering

Is there a way to number "Facts", similar to the way theorems, lemmas, and examples are numbered?

Comment: `\newcounter{facts}` and `\refstepcounter{facts}` and `\thefacts` -- but you should say, what `Facts` mean here. And welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1):

An easy starter, assuming a very basic `facts` environment and using a `facts` counter that resets within each new `section`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{facts}[section]


\renewcommand{\thefacts}{\thesection.\arabic{facts}}

\newenvironment{facts}{%
  \parindent=0em
  \refstepcounter{facts}
  \textbf{Facts \thefacts}

}{%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Facts section}

\begin{facts}
  Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin again at the other end.
\end{facts}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackagen{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{:}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{facts}{Facts}
```

defines such a numbered environment.